# How to solve Expected an identifier, but got ':'.Try inserting an identifier before ':'. error in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, switch-statement

I got this error :

Error: Expected an identifier, but got ':'.
Try inserting an identifier before ':'.

while trying to use the switch-case and I couldn't figure out what is wrong with my code

```
void main() {

  int day = 5;

  switch (day) {
    case : 1 {
        print("Monday");
      }
      break;

    case : 2 {
        print("Tuesday");
      }
      break;

    case : 3 {
        print("Wednesday");
      }
      break;

    case : 4 {
        print("Thursday");
      }
      break;

    case : 5 {
        print("Friday");
      }
      break;

    case : 6 {
        print("Saturday");
      }
      break;

    case : 7 {
      print("Sunday");
    }
    break;

    default : {
      print("There is no day like this");
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the colon must come after the value

```
void main() {
  int day = 5;

  switch (day) {
    case 1:
      {
        print("Monday");
      }
      break;

    case 2:
      {
        print("Tuesday");
      }
      break;

    case 3:
      {
        print("Wednesday");
      }
      break;

    case 4:
      {
        print("Thursday");
      }
      break;

    case 5:
      {
        print("Friday");
      }
      break;

    case 6:
      {
        print("Saturday");
      }
      break;

    case 7:
      {
        print("Sunday");
      }
      break;

    default:
      {
        print("There is no day like this");
      }
      break;
  }
}
```